# Gradle couldnt find recycleview-v7.jar but I already have recycleview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I have

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'
```

on my build.gradle(Module: app) file. When I sync the gradle files, it says couldn't find `recyclerview-v7.jar(com.android.support:recyclerview-v7: 24.1.1)`. Why isn't it building correctly now, I mean it already has built recyclerview-v7 jar file before succesfully(I've already used it without android adapters). how can I build android adapters without this error?

```
// Project level build.gradle file
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// App level build.gradle file
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.beacon.retailersgear"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'



    // RecyclerView and CardView
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'

    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'

}
```

Comment: can you post your full gradle file? do you also have a compileTree(*.jar) in there ?

Comment: do you use the same version 24.1.1 as the one it worked before? if not then maybe you don't have the update of "android repository" and "google repository".

Comment: yes I have the same version as the one it worked before

Comment: Try excluding `compile('io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}`

Comment: I tried it and it worked! thanked a lot @EpicPandaForce

Comment: in that case I undeleted my answer, I wasn't sure if this would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `realm:android-adapters` seems to bring in `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'`, so you should exclude it.

```
compile('io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

(although it's odd because I never had this problem before, despite using new version...)